# index.php blank page nginx php5-fpm with multiple site

Tags: php, nginx

I'm in this weird situation, I set up my nginx and everything is working fine until I change the index file of the second host from index.html to index.php. When I make this change the second host show a blank page.

```
#
# HOST 1
#

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name domain1.com;

       root /var/www/Folder1/public;
       index index.php;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}

#
# HOST 2
#

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name domain2.com;

       root /var/www/Folder2/public;
       index index.php;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Settings are the same but meanwhile for the first are working perfect, for the second no.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, is there an index.php file in the webroot of host 2 (`/var/www/Folder2/public`) that isn't echoing any html code?

Comment: yes, it's there. It's a laravel installation. So if something else wrong should print some errors.

Comment: it chooses `location /`. Use `try_files $uri =404;` inside the `location ~ \.php$` instead of the one inside `location /`

Comment: Have you tried a simple `index.php`? For example: `<?php phpinfo();` just to test that your `php-fpm` installation is working.

Comment: In the first host is working. Anyway I try with the second host too. @Deadooshka when trying your way throw this error the reload nginx `"try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5`

Comment: when nginx gets the root request `/`, it take `location /` where the `try_files` test it as a directory with positive result meaning that it stays in the location. So in this case it waits for index file there. Global `index` works in the last phase.

Comment: @RichardSmith with `phpinfo()` it's working. Is it possible that two host have different php version? like first 5.6 and second 7.0. I tried `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer update` and it throw `This package requires php ^7.0 but your PHP version (5.6.29) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Comment: Well, phpinfo should give you all of that information.